# Анимация заполнения водой

Tags: css, css3, svg, css-animation

Я пытаюсь сделать анимацию, чтобы круг выглядел так, будто он наполняется водой.

Я столкнулся с двумя ошибками и не смог даже преодолеть третью:

1. Использовать заполнение (fill) это неправильное решение.
2. Круг возвращается до пустого (черного) цвета после его заполнения
3. На данный момент я использую теги `<img>`, но я хотел бы переместить
   этот эффект в body `{background-image:}` и нужно какое-то
   направление, как это сделать.

То, что я пробовал до сих пор: http://jsfiddle.net/um0rnL56/1/

```css
#banner {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
#banner div {
  position: absolute;
}
#banner div:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: wipe 6s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-animation-direction: up;
  -webkit-mask-size: 300px 3000px;
  -webkit-mask-position: 300px 300px;
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.00, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(0.25, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(0.27, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(0.80, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(1.00, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
}
@-webkit-keyframes wipe {
  0% {
    -webkit-mask-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-mask-position: 300px 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <div>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vklf6kK.png" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/uszeRpk.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Источник: [Filling water animation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29738787/7394871) @Arian Faurtosh

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29738787/7394871

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Вот четыре разных варианта:

### 1. Используя Easing

Если вы заполняете жидкостью круглую  чашу, то она будет заполняться быстрее внизу и сверху, чем в середине (потому что в более широкой средней части больше места для покрытия)  Итак, с учетом этого грубого объяснения, анимация должна: начинаться быстро, замедляться посередине, а затем быстро заканчиваться, когда чаша сужается снова наверху.

Для этого мы можем использовать функцию easing CSS3: `cub-bezier (.2, .6, .8, .4)`.

Посмотрите пример ниже.

(Если вы хотите настроить `easing` здесь, то вот отличный ресурс: http://cubic-bezier.com/#.2,.6,.8,.4)

```css
#banner {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#banner::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #04ACFF;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  animation: wipe 5s cubic-bezier(.2,.6,.8,.4) forwards;
}
@keyframes wipe {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div id="banner">

</div>
```

### 2. SVG Deliciousness

Давайте сделаем еще один шаг вперед.  Допустим, мы захотим добавить волнистую поверхность на «воду» с помощью `CSS`. Мы можем сделать это, используя  `SVG`.
Я создал волнистый SVG image в `Adobe Illustrator`, а затем анимировал image, чтобы перемещать его слева направо в цикле с отдельной анимацией CSS:

**Пример**

```css
#banner {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
#banner .fill {
    animation-name: fillAction;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2, .6, .8, .4);
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
#banner #waveShape {
    animation-name: waveAction;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    width:300px;
    height: 150px;
    fill: #04ACFF;
}
@keyframes fillAction {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0, 150px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(0, -5px);
    }
}
@keyframes waveAction {
    0% {
        transform: translate(-150px, 0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
<div class="fill">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">
      <path fill="#04ACFF" id="waveShape" d="M300,300V2.5c0,0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.1c0,0-25.5-2.3-40.5-2.4c-15,0-40.6,2.4-40.6,2.4
 c-12.3,1.1-30.3,1.8-31.9,1.9c-2-0.1-19.7-0.8-32-1.9c0,0-25.8-2.3-40.8-2.4c-15,0-40.8,2.4-40.8,2.4c-12.3,1.1-30.4,1.8-32,1.9
 c-2-0.1-20-0.8-32.2-1.9c0,0-3.1-0.3-8.1-0.7V300H300z"/>
    </svg>
</div>
</div>
```

### 3. С  линией наполнения

Этот пример включает линию заливки (большинство чаш заполняется сверху, а не снизу). Линия заливки сначала анимируется сверху вниз, в то время как свойство `animation-delay` предотвращает выполнение анимации заливки до завершения заливки.

```css
#banner {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
}

#banner .fill {
  transform: translateY(150px);
  animation-name: fillAction;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2, .6, .8, .4);
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.25s;
}

#banner .pour {
  width: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3px;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #009ae6;
  animation-name: pourAction;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-duration: 0.25s;
}

#banner #waveShape {
  animation-name: waveAction;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  fill: #04ACFF;
}

@keyframes pourAction {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes fillAction {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(150px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-5px);
  }
}

@keyframes waveAction {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-150px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <div class="pour"></div>
  <div class="fill">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">
      <path fill="#04ACFF" id="waveShape" d="M300,300V2.5c0,0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.1c0,0-25.5-2.3-40.5-2.4c-15,0-40.6,2.4-40.6,2.4
c-12.3,1.1-30.3,1.8-31.9,1.9c-2-0.1-19.7-0.8-32-1.9c0,0-25.8-2.3-40.8-2.4c-15,0-40.8,2.4-40.8,2.4c-12.3,1.1-30.4,1.8-32,1.9
c-2-0.1-20-0.8-32.2-1.9c0,0-3.1-0.3-8.1-0.7V300H300z" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

### 4. С серьезным Bling (с красивой эстетикой)

Этот пример добавляет еще несколько свойств `CSS`, чтобы сделать его более реалистичным.

```css
.bowl {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), inset 0 -20px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset -15px 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 15px 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, transparent 0%, transparent 76%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, transparent 0%, transparent 76%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 76%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%);
  margin: 20px;
}
.bowl:before {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: "";
  box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), inset 0 -20px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset -15px 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 15px 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, transparent 0%, transparent 60%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 81%, black 100%);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, transparent 0%, transparent 60%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 81%, black 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 60%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 81%, #000000 100%);
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.bowl:after {
  content: "";
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 5px;
  background: #039be4;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 0 #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -30px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
.bowl .inner {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, transparent 0%, transparent 76%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, transparent 0%, transparent 76%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 76%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.bowl .inner:before {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 40%;
  top: 60%;
  z-index: 2;
}
.bowl .inner:after {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30%;
  top: 15%;
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
  z-index: 2;
}
.bowl .fill {
  -webkit-animation-name: fillAction;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.6, 0.8, 0.4);
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.bowl .waveShape {
  -webkit-animation-name: waveAction;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  fill: #039be4;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fillAction {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 150px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 10px);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes waveAction {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-150px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
/* For aesthetics only ------------------------------------------*/
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font: 200 1.2em "Segoe UI Light", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #fff;
  background: #039be4;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #ccc;
}
h1 strong {
  font-family: "Segoe UI Black";
  font-weight: normal;
}

.explanation {
  padding: 20px 40px;
  float: right;
  background: #e64a19;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 30px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-bottom: 10px solid #ccc;
  max-width: 300px;
}
.explanation p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="bowl">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="fill">
      <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">
        <path class="waveShape" d="M300,300V2.5c0,0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.1c0,0-25.5-2.3-40.5-2.4c-15,0-40.6,2.4-40.6,2.4
 c-12.3,1.1-30.3,1.8-31.9,1.9c-2-0.1-19.7-0.8-32-1.9c0,0-25.8-2.3-40.8-2.4c-15,0-40.8,2.4-40.8,2.4c-12.3,1.1-30.4,1.8-32,1.9
 c-2-0.1-20-0.8-32.2-1.9c0,0-3.1-0.3-8.1-0.7V300H300z" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Источник: [Filling water animation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29740828/7394871) @Chris Spittles

Comment: Diablo напомнило =)

Comment: Хороший перевод. )

Comment: @LexHobbit следующий вопрос: как на CSS добавить к моему шарику с водой ангела и демона.

Comment: @Alexandr_T - а где такому можно научиться? Это какой-то запредельный для меня уровень...

Comment: @Michael всё зависит от вас. Если будет огромное желание, то будут и результаты. Не хочется повторять прописных истин и нет конкретного адреса, где сразу, быстро можно овладеть знаниями. Изучайте, как можно больше источников, постоянно что-то пишите сами, но добивайтесь при этом 100% понимания кода и избегайте метода "тыка" и всё у вас получится.